# Change a string only on the first two rows of every new index change

Tags: c#

I have a very long List of strings that I am trying to manipulate. I want to rename the field 'description' to **Type** and **Process**, but only on the first two rows of every new number (1,2,3).

For instance:

```
1  description   Payment
1  description   Order
1  ID   0222ed48-ddc1-3e19-4770-616c14935ca1

2  description   Refund
2  description   Partial
2  description   Contacted?
2  ID    87f11531-0493-4f5a-86d2-c8be0c23678f

3  description   Refund
3  description   Partial
3  ID    87f11531-0493-4f5a-86d2-c8be0c23678f
```

**To this:** with a Type and Process only on the first two rows of every number change (1,2,3):

```
1  **Type**   Payment
1  **Process**   Order
1  ID   0222ed48-ddc1-3e19-4770-616c14935ca1

2  **Type**   Refund
2  **Process**   Partial
2  description   Contacted?
2  ID    87f11531-0493-4f5a-86d2-c8be0c23678f

3  **Type**   Refund
3  **Process**   Partial
3  ID    87f11531-0493-4f5a-86d2-c8be0c23678f
```

Should I try adding a counter to every loop that resets when greater that 2, thus swapping the first two rows out?

Comment: Could you share the code you're currently using, that isn't doing what you expect it to?

Comment: Thanks for the response; I'm not sure how to proceed. I tried a counter that resets at (x >2) for every new index change, but that didn't work.

Comment: Can you share that code? Maybe you were close and you didnt even realise it

Comment: Without generating a solution for you, a viable solution probably lies in using LINQ by first using `GroupBy` on your list, and grouping on the index, and then iterating over each grouped set of strings, only changing the first 2.

Comment: Is there always (and only there) an empty line before a new number?

Comment: No there is not, I have added this in to make things clearer.

Comment: ok. posted an answer that should work

Comment: Thank you for this, it did work, but it broke another piece of code elsewhere that relies on .NET 4.7. I'm looking at how to alter your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

namespace ConsoleApp3
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string foo = @"1  description   Payment
1  description   Order
1  ID   0222ed48-ddc1-3e19-4770-616c14935ca1

2  description   Refund
2  description   Partial
2  description   Contacted?
2  ID    87f11531-0493-4f5a-86d2-c8be0c23678f

3  description   Refund
3  description   Partial
3  ID    87f11531-0493-4f5a-86d2-c8be0c23678f";

            int number = 0;
            int line = 0;
            string bar = Regex.Replace(foo, @"^(\d+)(\s+)(\w+)", match => 
            {
                int currentNumber = Convert.ToInt32(match.Groups[1].Value);
                if (currentNumber == number)
                    line++;
                else
                {
                    number = currentNumber;
                    line = 1;
                }

                string newToken = line switch
                {
                    1 => "Type",
                    2 => "Process",
                    _ => match.Groups[3].Value
                };

                return match.Groups[1].Value + match.Groups[2].Value + newToken;
            }, RegexOptions.Multiline);
        }
    }
}
```

[EDIT] the switch maybe needs .NET 5